# How does $g^{x^2} \bmod p$ help you find $x$?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

I was thinking about the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. One fact that we seem to know is that given a group generator $g$, a prime $p$ and the expression $g^x \bmod p$ its believed to be hard to find $x$; or more accurately $x \bmod(p-1)$.

Now the question is, what if we gave away some extra information. Such as $g^{x^2} \bmod p$.

My guess is that surely this should help us find $x$ in some fashion, but it’s not clear how.

Finding an exponent that sends $g^x$ to $g^{x^2}$ is as hard as finding $x$ given just our usual initial data. So that’s probably not the right way to exploit this information.

Comment: Loosely related: [_Diffie-Hellman: difficulty of computing $g^{x^2}$ given $g^x$?_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82041/555), and the questions linked in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/182120).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not known that knowing $g^{x^2}$ would help in any meaningful way to solve the discrete logarithm problem.

What you are describing can be generalized to asking whether in a group $\mathbb{G}$ giving an attacker $$(g, g^x,g^{x^2},\dots,g^{x^q})$$ for some $q$ and a uniformly chosen $x \in |\mathbb{G}|$ makes it feasible to recover $x$.

It is generally assumed that this is not the case. In fact the assumption that recovering $x$ remains hard is called the $q$-strong discrete logarithm ($q$-SDL) assumption and has been used before. [[GOR11]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/233) Similarly, the bilinear variant is also assumed to be hard. [[FS20]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1301)

While the $q$-SDL assumption itself is not used very often, it is actually implied by a variety of much more commonly used variants of $q$-strong Diffie Hellman assumptions. [[TS10]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/215)

---

[[GOR11]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/233) Vipul Goyal, Adam O'Neill, and Vanishree Rao. "Correlated-Input Secure Hash Functions". TCC 2011

[[FS20]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1301) Nils Fleischhacker and Mark Simkin. "Robust Property-Preserving Hash Functions for Hamming Distance and More". Cryptology ePrint Archive, Report 2020/1301, 2020

[[TS10]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/215) Naoki Tanaka and Taiichi Saito, "On the $q$-Strong Diffie-Hellman Problem". Cryptology ePrint Archive, Report 2010/215, 2010