# DH Key Exchange Protocol

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, oblivious-transfer

Since I am not able to comment under the topic, I would like to ask here why in question 2 [old post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42213/dh-key-exchange-protocol-one-out-of-two), we cannot distinguish the two distributions, even with unlimited computational power? Also, what can be said about the distribution of exponents a+b modp when b is taken at random from Zp, but a is fixed?

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to take the questions out of order.

> what can be said about the distribution of exponents a+b mod p when b is taken at random from Zp, but a is fixed?

If $b$ is a uniform independent random value from the range $[0, p-1]$, that is, the probability of each possible value is $1/p$, and $b$ is distributed independently from $a$, then $a+b \bmod p$ is a uniform independent (of $a$) random value from the range $[0, p-1]$; that is, the probability of $a+b \bmod p$ being any possible value from the range is also $1/p$, and information about the distribution of $a$ (such as having it be a fixed value) does not change this.

The easiest way to see this (for a fixed $a$) is to note that, for any target value $c = a+b \bmod p$, there is a unique value of $b = c-a \bmod p$ that must be selected for the value $a+b \bmod p$ to be that value.  The probability of $b = c-a \bmod p$ occurring is $1/p$ (because that value is in the range, and we assumed the probability of all values in that range be $1/p$), hence the probability that $c = a+b \bmod p$ is also $1/p$.

With this, your first question is easy:

> I would like to ask here why in question 2 old post, we cannot distinguish the two distributions, even with unlimited computational power?

Alice sees either $g^b$ or $g^{a+b}$; an adversary with unlimited computational power can solve the discrete log, however that gives him either $b$ or $a+b$ (for random $b$); both probability distributations are identical, and so he cannot distinguish them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One last question. Why the value of a must be a fixed value?

Comment: @user178592: it doesn't - the only requirement is that b be distributed independently of a.  Assuming a fixed a just make the demonstration easier..