# Is it safe to derive secret from alice's private key and alice's public key?

Tags: public-key, secret-sharing

I'm using secp256k1; in normal scenario `alice.privateKey` and `bob.publicKey` (or vice versa) is used to derive the same `secret`.

Is it safe to use `alice.privateKey` and `alice.publicKey` to derive `secret` as a key for encryption for alice's personal information - where `alice.publicKey` and encrypted blob is publicly available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, recovering the computed secret is as hard as doing it for conventional Diffie-Hellman and thus infeasible for any secure groups.

This is known as Square-Diffie-Hellman problem, the reduction to the *computational Diffie-Hellman problem* (CDH) can be found in [this Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12581/23623).

Comment: It does however seem unwise. In addition to whatever cipher you use you now also introduce the additional attack surface of ECC.

Comment: @dingrite Actually I can see the point of doing this. For example consider a smartcard / HSM with an ECDH engine (which would provide you with eg a CDH oracle) but without a symmetric keystore. You can then use this HW device to hardware-enforce your "symmetric" key(s).

Comment: Is it required to input a salt or something similar as used in static-static DH key agreement? It seems to me that you would otherwise always derive the same secret.